# Facebook is unable to access share link of my web application

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-sharer, facebook-share

I am trying to share content to facebook using below share Link

```
https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://myeatapp.com/shareSocials/itemShare/1069
```

But facebook share link is unable to scrape provide url in the parameter, Below are the error i am getting while tried to access it using facebook debugger

While providing http://myeatapp.com/shareSocials/itemShare/1069 as a link:

- Error parsing input URL, no data was cached, or no data was scraped.

And when Link is https://myeatapp.com/shareSocials/itemShare/1069 as a link below error occurs:

- Object at URL '(AboveURl)' of type 'website' is invalid because a required property 'og:title' of type 'string' was not provided.
- Curl Error : SSL_PEER_CERTIFICATE SSL: certificate subject name 'localhost' does not match target host name 'myeatapp.com'

Is it related to DNS or something else?

Comment: 1. You have `<meta property="og:url" content="https://www.facapps.com" />` in there – so Facebook will try and fetch the meta data from _that_ URL. 2. Fix your SSL. Looks like you are using only a self-signed certificate here. If you want this to work outside of your dev environment, then you need to get a “real” SSL cert.

Comment: @CBroe Apology, actually link i was trying to share is http://myeatapp.com/shareSocials/itemShare/1069 this one, facebook share is working for https://www.facapps.com. I need to run this for http://myeatapp.com/shareSocials/itemShare/1069 Link